# BizTalk 2016 Server Administration - Instance of the WMI class is not found

Tags: certificate, biztalk

I am brand new to BizTalk administration and trying to setup the certificate to use for AS2 communication, and running into some problems. The developer who built everything inside BizTalk did it under one account, domain\developer, but everything actually runs under domain\biztalk.

All processing works great (meaning BizTalk can talk to the various databases on the local SQL Server), but when I am logged in as domain\biztalk and go to configure the AS2 certificate it seems like things get tripped up. According to this link (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/configuring-certificates-for-as2), the certificate has to be in the Personal store of the user BizTalk runs under, so I've imported that. When I open up the Server Administration Console though, I expand BizTalk Server Administration, then expand BizTalk Group and receive this error:

[image: BizTalk Server Administration]

According to a couple of different links pointing to MSDN forums, it was suggested to restart the WMI service and it started working, but that didn't do it for me.

Where it gets really strange is, since all development was done under domain\developer, I logged in as that account and expanding BizTalk Server Administration Console works - I can see all options (Applications, Parties and Platform Settings). When I go in to Parties and try to configure the certificate, I receive back a "No certificate available. No certificates meet the application criteria." error. I'm sure this is because I need to link the certificate to the domain\biztalk account, but since the SnapIn stuff doesn't load, I'm at a loss on how to proceed.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What groups does the biztalk user have?  I hope that isn't the BIzTalk host user account.